# Using Netty HttpProxyHandler

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am implementing a Netty Client which is behind a corporate proxy (actually, I am trying to customize Camel's netty-http component to use an http proxy).

When I use my client configuration directly, without HttpProxyHandler (on a machine outside the corporate network), it works. But when I run the code on a machine inside the corporate network, I get this error message (target host anonymized):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Cannot connect to myserver.example.de:443
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyProducer$ChannelConnectedListener.operationComplete(NettyProducer.java:699)
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyProducer$ChannelConnectedListener.operationComplete(NettyProducer.java:685)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:110)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:89)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:214)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myserver.example.de
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1257)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
    ... 23 more
```

This is how I initialize the client. Notice the HttpProxyHandler right after the SSLHandler, this is what I did to get support for a corporate proxy.

```
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        // create a new pipeline
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        SslHandler sslHandler = configureClientSSLOnDemand();
        if (sslHandler != null) {
            LOG.debug("Client SSL handler configured and added as an interceptor against the ChannelPipeline: {}", sslHandler);
            pipeline.addLast("ssl", sslHandler);
        }

        HttpProxyHandler httpProxyHandler = new HttpProxyHandler(
                new InetSocketAddress("myproxy.corporate.de", 3128));
        pipeline.addLast("httpproxy", httpProxyHandler);

        pipeline.addLast("http", new HttpClientCodec());


        List<ChannelHandler> encoders = producer.getConfiguration()
            .getEncodersAsList();
        for (int x = 0; x < encoders.size(); x++) {
            ChannelHandler encoder = encoders.get(x);
            if (encoder instanceof ChannelHandlerFactory) {
                // use the factory to create a new instance of the channel as it may not be shareable
                encoder = ((ChannelHandlerFactory) encoder).newChannelHandler();
            }
            pipeline.addLast("encoder-" + x, encoder);
        }

        List<ChannelHandler> decoders = producer.getConfiguration()
            .getDecodersAsList();
        for (int x = 0; x < decoders.size(); x++) {
            ChannelHandler decoder = decoders.get(x);
            if (decoder instanceof ChannelHandlerFactory) {
                // use the factory to create a new instance of the channel as it may not be shareable
                decoder = ((ChannelHandlerFactory) decoder).newChannelHandler();
            }
            pipeline.addLast("decoder-" + x, decoder);
        }
        if (configuration.isDisableStreamCache()) {
            pipeline.addLast("inbound-streamer", new HttpInboundStreamHandler());
        }
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(configuration.getChunkedMaxContentLength()));
        pipeline.addLast("outbound-streamer", new HttpOutboundStreamHandler());

        if (producer.getConfiguration()
            .getRequestTimeout() > 0) {
            if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
                LOG.trace("Using request timeout {} millis", producer.getConfiguration()
                    .getRequestTimeout());
            }
            ChannelHandler timeout
                = new ReadTimeoutHandler(producer.getConfiguration()
                .getRequestTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            pipeline.addLast("timeout", timeout);
        }

        // handler to route Camel messages
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpClientChannelHandler(producer));
    }
```

The ProxyHandler.handlerAdded method gets called, which in turn calls HttpProxyHandler.addCodec. There, the http proxy handler adds its inner class HttpClientCodecWrapper using addBefore("httpproxy", null, codecWrapper). The HttpClientCodecWrapper receives its handlerAdded event and passes it on to the wrapped HttpClientCodec. The HttpClientCodec sets up its inboundCtx and outboundCtx and records it has been been added by setting handlerAdded=true.

Then, ProxyHandler.handlerAdded finds that ctx.channel().isActive is false and does nothing.

The ProxyHandler.channelActive event never gets fired, and ProxyHandler.connect never gets called. Instead, my netty pipeline tells me it cannot connnect to the target host, because it tries to resolve the target host using the corporate DNS, rather than leaving that to the http proxy.

This happens in the Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0() method, i.e. fairly deep down in Netty code.

What am I doing wrong? How can I convince my pipeline not to resolve the target host and directly go to the http proxy instead?

Comment: It turns out, when using the HttpProxyHandler, one should disable resolution:

bootstrap.resolver(NoopAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)

New problem: SSL fails when routed through the proxy. Thanks to yawcat from the Netty Discord forum!